# Terraform google_compute_firewall not accepting project variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I am trying to deploy one firewall rule in multiple projects I declare in variable file. I have created terraform module for this.  Below is my parent module's `main.tf` file.

```
module "google_iap_access_fw_rule" {
  source        = "../../modules/networking/firewall"
  for_each      = var.vpc-subnets
  project       = each.value.project_id
  network       = each.value.vpc_name
  name          = "${each.value.vpc_name}-allow-iap"
  protocol      = "tcp"
  ports         = [22, 3389]
  source_ranges = ["35.235.240.0/20"] # Google IAP access range, do not modify
  source_tags   = []
  target_tags   = [] # Rule applies to all instances in the network
}
```

Below is my `terraform.tfvars` file,

```
vpc-subnets = {
  vpc-subnet-01 = {
    project_id = "PROJECT_ID_1"
    vpc_name   = "vpc-01"
  },
  vpc-subnet-02 = {
    project_id = "PROJECT_ID_2"
    vpc_name   = "vpc-02"
  }
}
```

Below is my child module looks like,

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "new-firewall" {
  project  = var.project
  name     = var.name
  network  = var.network
  disabled = var.disabled

  allow {
    protocol = var.protocol
    ports    = var.ports
  }

  target_tags   = var.target_tags
  source_ranges = var.source_ranges
  source_tags   = var.source_tags
}
```

when I try to run this code, I get below error

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 26, in module "google_iap_access_fw_rule":
│   4:   project       = each.value.project_id
│ 
│ An argument named "project" is not expected here.
╵
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: When looking through our TF-code, I can't find for_each used with module. I believe you should use for_each with resource.

Comment: @RoarS. If you look carefully I have used `for_each` in module. Line number 3.

Comment: @Rahul what does the `variables.tf` file from the module look like?

Comment: @Rahul, what version of terraform and version of google provider did you use?